# Is this notation, $\{(x_i, y_i) \mid (x_i, y_i) \in \mathcal{D}, x_i^{(j)} = c\}$, legal and clear from set theory perspective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, machine-learning

In machine learning, an ordered pair $(x_i,y_i)$ denotes $i^{th}$ example in the training set $\mathcal{D}$, where $\mathcal{D} = \{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2), ..., (x_m,y_m)\}$.

each examples has n features, denoted 
$x_i = (x_i^{(1)}, ..., x_i^{(n)})$, where $x^{(j)}_i$ denotes the $j^{th}$ feature of $i^{th}$ example.

some leaning methods such as decision tree, learn models by partitioning training data.

I would like to use this notation to denote the partitioned data

$\{(x_i, y_i) \mid (x_i, y_i) \in \mathcal{D}, x_i^{(j)} = c\}$, where c is the value used to partition training data, j is the feature that is being considered to partition training data.

is this notation legal and clear from set theory perspective?

PS: sorry for previous misleading version.

Comment: The notation is clear, however I would personally use $\{(x_i,y_i)\in\mathcal D\mid x_i=c\}$ or $\{(c,y_i)\mid (c,y_i)\in\mathcal D\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing.  The use of i is not set builder syntax.
It is understandable only because of your explanation.
Clear ways of describing that set:
{ (x,y) : (x,y) in D, x = c },
{ x : x in D, $\pi_1$(x) = c }.
Clearer but not recommended
{ $(x_i,y_i)$ : i in index set of D, $x_i$ = c }.

Comment: Sorry for previous misleading version. I've updated my question, would you please take a loot at that again?

Comment: @JJJohn.  Are the x's unique?   Are the y's unique?  Are entries in the training set unique?

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_i$ is constant,
I would write it as
$\{(c, y_i) \mid (c, y_i) \in \mathcal{D}\}
$.

Comment: Sorry for previous misleading version. I've updated my question, would you please take a loot at that again?